# The horrible empty space!!!!! (on MSO only)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, profile-page, meta

In your user profile on MSO, it is a clone of the SO profile.  But unfortunately there is one big difference.  Since there is no reputation on the site, the reputation chart is not provided, leaving only an empty gray void.

[image: The horrible empty void]

[As Keiwan correctly recalled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351563/the-horrible-empty-space-on-mso-only?noredirect=1#comment487340_351563), this empty space didn't always exist, so had to been changed in one of the recent redesigns (courtesy of [webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20151012184749/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/250725/psubsee2003?tab=topactivity)).

[image: What it used to look like from WebArchive]

Can we put something in there, either revert to the previous workaround or something else?  Maybe allow users to track 2 different tag badges on meta.  Or maybe track voting on meta posts (or even show hypothetical meta rep).  Heck, even allow a user customizable community ad (open source software or an Area 51 proposal, or an add for new beta site to help attract attention).

Or what about random pictures of [waffles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19480#19480) or [unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19479#19479), or [just a freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775).

Anything would be better than an empty gray void.

Comment: I've an idea, lets fill it with unicorns.

Comment: @BhargavRao you inspired my upcoming edit.

Comment: Looks like the ideal place to add some [spam](https://image.ibb.co/nfo0QF/Capture.png)

Comment: I would swear that a reputation chart *used* to be visible here, and was only removed with the last profile page redesign. Am I just imagining that, or was it formerly populated with our magic Meta repz?

Comment: @CodyGray Just for reference, [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160417202017/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray?tab=topactivity) is what it looked like.

Comment: @Keiwan thanks.  That explains why I never noticed it before.  I looked so out of place I was shocked that I couldn't find it

Comment: Looks like a regression to me. That earlier fill looked fine. What up for testing...

Comment: @Keiwan Come on SE folks, you most probably have more important stuff to do than uglifying meta user profiles!

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος as Lightness Races in Orbit points out, it is very possibly a regression, so I've rearranged the answer to point out the previous look and made that being the first best option more obvious.

Comment: OCD army ASSEMBLE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been corrected and now displays the way it used to. Sorry about the wait fixing this bug.

This is what the Activity box now looks like on Meta:

[image: Reputation now stretches across the entire Reputation card.]